# Uploading Java to a website doesn't works

Tags: java, servlets, web

I have uploaded on a... let's say www.mywebsite.com a /helloservlet/ and into /helloservlet/ I have an index.html that shows a simple Hello World! This works fine but if I want to put an Java app, I uploaded a /WEB-INF/web.xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>mypkg.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/sayhello</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and in /helloservlet/WEB-INF/src/mypkg/HelloServlet.java with

```
package mypkg;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
   @Override
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
               throws IOException, ServletException {
      // Set the response message's MIME type
      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
      // Allocate a output writer to write the response message into the network socket
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      // Write the response message, in an HTML page
      try {
         out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
         out.println("<html><head>");
         out.println("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>");
         out.println("<title>Hello, World</title></head>");
         out.println("<body>");
         out.println("<h1>Hello, world!</h1>");  // says Hello
         // Echo client's request information
         out.println("<p>Request URI: " + request.getRequestURI() + "</p>");
         out.println("<p>Protocol: " + request.getProtocol() + "</p>");
         out.println("<p>PathInfo: " + request.getPathInfo() + "</p>");
         out.println("<p>Remote Address: " + request.getRemoteAddr() + "</p>");
         // Generate a random number upon each request
         out.println("<p>A Random Number: <strong>" + Math.random() + "</strong></p>");
         out.println("</body>");
         out.println("</html>");
      } finally {
         out.close();  // Always close the output writer
      }
   }
}
```

but when I try

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/helloservlet/sayhello
```

It gives me an error.
What is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the log files?

Comment: it said AH00128: File does not exist: /htdocs/sayhello but I thought /sayhello is mapped in web.xml to the Java class...

Comment: Are you using an application server like Tomcat? And if you are, did you try compiling your code to a .war and uploading that?

Comment: No because I thought tomcat is just for localhost (on my machine) but to upload a page to a website how can I put my tomcat there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Java application server on the machine that should host your code, like Tomcat. Then upload the .war to this Tomcat instance (or glassfish or whatever) this should fix your issue.